# Getting familiar with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have not fully learned the features of Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  I know some functionality that others have showed me, but that's it.

What are some recommended video tutorials with the main highlights and good tips and tricks?

I want to convince my IT dept/manager to upgrade to Ultimate edition. What justifications or reasons can I bring to the decision makers to convince them? What fundamental adventages does Visual Studio Ultimate have over Visual Studio Professional?

Comment: As far as the last question is concerned - look at the features for each edition, found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/products), see which features are things you can use to convince others (there is a download there too).

Comment: Have you really checked out MSDN docs?

Comment: thanks, i saw tha before - but is it enough? I think I need provide him some concrete examples. Do you know such?

Comment: Are you sure Ultimate will solve a problem you are having? You need to show your employer why this is worth their money.

Comment: What are you guys using for source control software?  To my knowledge, that's the main difference - Ultimate includes MS's Team Foundation collaboration / source control software.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at bullet point 3 off of this link for several relevant videos

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff431702

You can compare version features here

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

To identify concrete examples of why to upgrade, you'll have to think about what areas are less-than-optimal in your current work.  For example, Ultimate provides tools for Architecture and Modeling that Pro does not.  Do those matter to you?  There are also more debugging tools (IntelliTrace, Static Code Analysis, Code Metrics, Profiling).  Will that make your team more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Pluralsight have a number of Visual Studio courses, they're pay for view though -

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses#visual-studio

Whilst I haven't seen any of the Visual Studio courses the standard of Pluralsight content is generally very high.